# Workaround for SQL Server PHP 8.3 driver not available yet?

Tags: php, sql-server, driver

While waiting for approval to downgrade my client's PHP version to 8.2, I'm wondering if anyone here has found a workaround to enable SQL Server support on PHP 8.3. So far I have managed to connect using `php_odbc`, but it has a lot of drawbacks, performance included.

What I'm asking for is workaround, and not recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more, because it is not what I needed and certainly don't meet Stack Overflow guidelines.

So far the contents of Microsoft SQL Server driver download only lists up to PHP 8.2 driver files

[image]

Comment: There's no workaround except to use php 8.2 until the driver is released

Comment: This happens with absolutely every PHP major release. Microsoft doesn't upgrade drivers until several months afterwards, I guess because they only really care about .NET. Not sure how it's possible that a fully untested upgrade got approved yet you aren't allowed to revert when it didn't work, but I guess that's how many companies work. 

Comment: And that is why I asked the question here, since its been going on for long, whether anyone has come across a better way, whether to tweak the parameters, do changes in configs or whatever. Because I'm stuck to waiting if the client doesn't want to downgrade.

Comment: I guess the only alternative would be to compile the module from source, but you'll hit bugs with every feature that needs changes for new versions.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently on PHP 8.3.0 in my dev environment and I am utilizing [Microsoft PHP SQL Driver - BETA](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases) driver that works just fine. This may be an acceptable work around for you until they release the production version. I am by no means condoning using this in a production environment, but it is an option.

Comment: Thank you, it works just fine. I'm using it while still monitoring for issues